# Disco Dingo PyCharm 'Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2' while everything else runs Python 3

Tags: apt, python, virtualenv, pycharm

I uninstalled `Virtualenv 16.6.0`. I'm using `PyCharm` with `virtualenv version 15.1.0`. **Update**: Tried the creating `/venv` in create projects but the message is this there and now the `venv directory` is yellow. When I type `virtualenv` I get:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
You must provide a DEST_DIR
Usage: virtualenv.py [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```

Everything else runs `Python 3.7`

```
apt policy python3-django
python3-django:
  Installed: 1:1.11.20-1ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 1:1.11.20-1ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.11.20-1ubuntu0.2 500

raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"

apt policy python3-virtualenv
python3-virtualenv:
  Installed: 15.1.0+ds-2
  Candidate: 15.1.0+ds-2

sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
python3-virtualenv is already the newest version (15.1.0+ds-2).
python3-virtualenv set to manually installed.
```

**Update:** Tried both commands

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
python3-pip is already the newest version (18.1-5).

pip3 install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (15.1.0)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to on `PyCharm-`was the click on the bottom right of the screen, the current interpreter- change to `Python 3` - then it installed `Python 3.8` on `Pycharm`.

Answer (score 0):

Install virtualenv with pip3 and it will default to using python3 as the interpreter

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install virtualenv
```

If all you are looking to do is set your virtual environment to python3 then you would use the command

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.x (name of your environment here)
```

For PyCcharm to use python3 you have to do it from within PyCharm itself. The remainder of my response is taken directly from [https://www.cs.rit.edu/~csci141/Docs/PyCharm-Setup.html](https://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Ecsci141/Docs/PyCharm-Setup.html).

> On the welcome screen, go to the lower right of the window and select
> Configure -> Settings (or Preferences) -> Default Project -> Project
> Interpreter.
>
> In the settings window, you will now configure the default projects
> you make in PyCharm to use Python 3.
>
> When the setting dialog comes up, select the Project Interpreter to
> choose the Python 3 interpreter that you just installed.
>
> Turn off the default use of venv for projects. You should see a
> settings button (e.g. gear) for adding an interpreter. Instead, choose
> the system interpreter to override the venv.
>
> Now select the OK button at the bottom and PyCharm will do the updates
> back on the welcome screen.
>
> You will now turn off the style warnings for what's known as "PEP 8",
> Python's style enforcement. (We do not use standard Python style in
> this course.) You do this by opening the preferences, selecting
> "Inspections" under Editor -> CodeStyle, and unchecking the "PEP 8"
> violation checkboxes as shown below. You can search for "pep" to find
> this more quickly than scrolling.
>
> Finally you can turn off the authorship line in the Editor's Code
> Templates for Python by erasing the whole line containing the
> **author** text in the template; you can see the line in the screen below. (You may want to visit the templates later to customize them.)
>
> You can then use the following code to test your settings.
> **NOTE** python3-tk must be installed `sudo apt install python3-tk`
>
> ```
>  """ sample.py is a sample python3 program using turtle graphics. """
>
>  python  import turtle    def drawSquare():
>  """
>  drawSquare draws a square with sides of length 100.
>  """
>  turtle.forward(100)
>  turtle.left(90)
>  turtle.forward(100)
>  turtle.left(90)
>  turtle.forward(100)
>  turtle.left(90)
>  turtle.forward(100)
>  turtle.left(90)    def main():
>  """
>  main program draws a square and waits user to hit Enter key.
>  """
>  drawSquare()
>  print('Close the canvas window to end the program...')
>  turtle.done()    if __name__ == '__main__':
>  main()
> ```
>
> You can first run the code by right-clicking in the code window and
> selecting Run sample. If everything is correct, you should see a
> separate Python turtle drawing window come up, and the console should
> open in the bottom pane of PyCharm.

Comment: I get this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: @SeemsToBeStuck added a bolded note in the middle of my answer. Install python3-tk ``sudo apt install python3-tk``

Comment: @SeemsToBeStuck any luck with this?